# cannot echo self delete command in another batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, self, batch-delete

i have a file named as new.bat.

1. using echo creates another "1.bat" batch file and writes code in it
2. self delete command is also added in 1.bat
3. 1.bat is run by `start /MIN 1.bat`

my main file (new.bat) file is getting deleted and cmd process exit, leaving behind 1.bat which i want to delete.

i know `del "%~f0" & exit` with this command self batch file is deleted, but wrong batch file is deleted

here are my below files

New.bat

```
echo echo 1 >>1.bat
echo del "%~f0" & exit >>1.bat
start /MIN 1.bat
```

pl Help

Comment: i have also tried this command, with this, file is deleted but the new cmd windows opened by 1.bat doesn't exit

Comment: i need to exit thae 2nd cmd window and return to the new.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```bat
Echo Echo 1 >>1.bat
Echo Del "%%~f0" ^& Exit >>1.bat
Start /MIN 1.bat
```

Or:

```bat
(   Echo Echo 1
    Echo Del "%%~f0" ^& Exit
)>1.bat
Start /MIN 1.bat
```

Comment: The reason being that in the original code the `%~f0` was being interpreted _inside_ `new.bat` and so was adding a command to delete `new.bat` to `1.bat`. The double `%%` prevents interpretation by the `echo` command, so that `del "%~f0"` ends up in `1.bat` and when _that_ command is run, it correctly deletes `1.bat`.